# How to get array from dropdown and input box values to loop over total number in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple drop down and corresponding number input fields like this:

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control category-select" name="category[]">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control category-number" name="no_of_category[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control category-select" name="category[]">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control category-number" name="no_of_category[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```

If user selects

1. option A and 2 as number
2. option B and 3 as number

Then I want Array something like following so that I can loop over total no of category with name.

```
A -> 1
A -> 1
B -> 1
B -> 1
B -> 1
```

Since Array can't have same index, This is not possible. But, What I actually want is loop over total number of category along with category name. Is there any way to achieve something similar to loop similar to above ?

Any kind of suggestion appreciated.

Comment: have you heard of jquery objects?

Comment: Sagar, do you want to get the array by a button click or while the user make the input?

Comment: @madalinivascu I'm new to jquery, I have done this before in php associative array like this: `array(0=>array(A=>1), 1=>array(A=>1), 2=>array(B=>1)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're "Wanted" result don't look like an array in jquery, but maybe this will help you create what you want.

```js
$('.category-select, .category-number').change(function() {
  var rowParent = $(this).closest(".row").parent();
  var obj = [];
  $(rowParent).children(".row").each(function() {
    var row = $(this)
    var selectVal = $(row).find("select").val();
    var inputVal = $(row).find("input").val();

    if (inputVal !== "") {
      for (i = 0; i < inputVal; i++){
        obj.push(selectVal)
      }
    }
  });
  if (obj.length > 0) console.log(obj)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control category-select" name="category[]">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control category-number" type="number" name="no_of_category[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control category-select" name="category[]">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control category-number" type="number" name="no_of_category[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```